# How do you dynamically assign a Master Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to assign a Master Page dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the master page in `PreInit` of the page whos `MasterPage` you wish to dynamically set:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/YourMaster.master";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the master page during the `Page_PreInit` by using the `MasterPageFile` property.

```
Me.MasterPageFile = "~/masterpage.master"
```